# How to set the value of UIPicker View with respect to the value fetched from the database?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

There are two picker view in a given UI: name and gender, how shall i proceed with respect to showing the user the selected value that has been set the last time the user updated the data in the database ?.

Have searched quite a few topics with respect to it the one that i found close to my description was https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow

There is no textview or label that has been set to capture the value as it messes up the view layout [The user Interface pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlT7q.png)

However i tried setting up one pickerView for multiple text boxes with the if condition ontextEdit, how ever the pickerView did'nt work. So set the UI as stated above.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, you're trying to set the data in your picker view as the data from a DB?

Comment: yea i mean its kind of update profile. Like the user gets the option of changing the data by scrolling and on saving it saves into database and when goes back to update the data, they will find the last updated data selected

Answer (score 0):

To set your pickerView you should use this method:
`open func selectRow(_ row: Int, inComponent component: Int, animated: Bool) // scrolls the specified row to center.`

And to save your user's choice you can use the method didFinishEditing, and find the new value there:
`yourPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)`

Regards

Comment: I did this and it pops out an error saying binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'UIpickerview'.                     open func selectRow(_ row: Int, inComponent component: Int, animated: Bool){
        if pickerView==userGenderPicker
        {
            selectedGender=self.gender[row]
        }
        else if pickerView==userBranchPicker
        {
            selectedBranch=self.branch[row]
        }else if pickerView==userYearPicker
        {
            selectedYear=self.year[row]
        }

    }